# html footer appearing inside wrapper?

Tags: html, css, css-position, footer

I tried the clear:both and body position as relative but still its always showing up higher inside the wrapper for some reason, any help would be greatly appreciated

here is the code on jsfiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/38xhn4dz/

here is the code I was working on :

```
<center>
  <img src="images/eshop.jpg" width="800px" height="120px"/>
</center>
<div id="menu">
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li>
      <a href="#" >
        HOME
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        HOT ITEMS
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        SELL TO US
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        ABOUT US
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        CONTACT
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="wrap">
  <center>
    <div class="box">
      <h3>
        Neutrogena Body Wash
      </h3>
      <p float="left">
        <img src="images/item1.jpg" width="50%" height="200px" alt="item1"/>
      </p>
      <h4>
        3$
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h3>
        Summer Boots
      </h3>
      <p float="left">
        <img src="images/item2.png" width="50%" height="200px" alt="item2"/>
      </p>
      <h4>
        5$
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h3>
        Samsung Galaxy S4
      </h3>
      <p float="left">
        <img src="images/item3.jpg" width="50%" height="200px" alt="item3"/>
      </p>
      <h4>
        500$
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h3>
        Liquid Perfume
      </h3>
      <p float="left">
        <img src="images/item4.gif" width="50%" height="200px" alt="item4"/>
      </p>
      <h4>
        10$
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h3>
        ASUS Laptop i3
      </h3>
      <p float="left">
        <img src="images/item5.png" width="50%" height="200px" alt="item5"/>
      </p>
      <h4>
        400$
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h3>
        Sony PS2 VGA
      </h3>
      <p float="left">
        <img src="images/item6.jpg" width="50%" height="200px" alt="item6"/>
      </p>
      <h4>
        7$
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h3>
        8GB Memory Card
      </h3>
      <p float="left">
        <img src="images/item7.jpg" width="50%" height="200px" alt="item7"/>
      </p>
      <h4>
        12$
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h3>
        2GB DDR3 RAM
      </h3>
      <p float="left">
        <img src="images/item8.jpg" width="50%" height="200px" alt="item8"/>
      </p>
      <h4>
        20$
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h3>
        50" LED TV
      </h3>
      <p float="left">
        <img src="images/item9.jpg" width="50%" height="200px" alt="item9"/>
      </p>
      <h4>
        999$
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
      <a href="#">
        <h4>
          Next Page
        </h4>
      </a>
    </div>
  </center>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    test
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
#wrap{
    width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top: 5em;
}
.box{
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    height:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
}   
.box2{
    float:right;
    width:30%;  
    margin:0 auto;
}
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:#ee5;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: How do you want it to render? `#footer { position: fixed }` maybe?

Comment: So you are wanting the yellow footer box at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Yes. He wants it at the bottom of the page.  @mrahmat, Your CSS is good, I'm thinking your HTML has a syntax error?

Comment: @Kie21 yes I want the footer at the bottom of the page, i dont want fixed position as it will keep the footer visible even when i am not scrolled down

Comment: @Godisgood i thought of that too but i could not find out where the error is

Comment: I created an answer.  The problem was the absolute positioning in the footer's CSS.  Jsfiddle is in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the `position:absolute`.  As @JimmyRare pointed out, the absolute positioning was positioned relative to the window.  So just remove the absolute positioning, and your footer will be placed back in the normal document flow.

[JSFIDDLE PROOF HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ianhazzard/38xhn4dz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Your footer is absolute positioned relative to the window and is not inside your wrapper.
Try making the window larger and you'll see that the footer will stay at the bottom.
This type of positioning will, however not re-position when you scroll and is probably the reason you thought it rendered inside the wrapper.

Maybe this is more what you are looking for? Simply removing the absolute positioning and just put it after all content.

```
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    background:#ee5;
    clear: both;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38xhn4dz/)

Comment: yeah I just tried it out and found out the wrapper seems to be the problem, do you know of a way to fix the wrapper positioning without messing it up?

Comment: How would you like your footer to behave? I edited your fiddle with how I usually handle a footer.

Answer (score -1):

Try this for the footer in the css

```
#footer {
width:100%;
height:80px;
position:absolute;
top:250%;
left:0;
background:#ee5;
clear: both;

}
```

You may have to adjust the % slightly

Comment: What if he adds more content to the page?  This is not a good solution . . .

Comment: Then the % can be changed to suit the needs of his sight

Comment: Just putting it as a block level element would be much more effective.  In the normal document flow.

Comment: Well thanks for telling me that. Ill keep that in mind next time I try this on my next project.

Comment: Welcome.  Not trying to pick on you.  This site is all about learning and more efficient coding.  Lesson learned - happy coding!